# Using 11.1v for a 9.6v motor

Tags: motor, batteries

I have a DC motor that uses 9.6 volt batteries. Can I use 3 of my 3.7 volt lithium-ion polymer batteries (11.1 V) to power this motor?

Somebody please help me. I have tried 2 of the LiPo (7.4v) and it could not give me the expected result. I am currently scared of burning my DC motor. I do not have access to 9.6v batteries.

Also if there would be a possible circuit that can step down the voltage please do help me with it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You want a switch-mode ("Buck") voltage regulator.

Comment: Check the motor specs.

Comment: Lithium batteries provide 4.2V when full. 3.7 is the average voltage. So three full batteries will give you 12.6V.

Answer (score 2):

Just put 2 silicon diodes in series between the 11.1V battery and the motor.

You will have 11.1 - 1.4 = 9.7V which should be fine.

Just pick 2 diodes that have enough current capacity for your motor.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

> i am currently scared of burning my dc motor.

most likely an non-issue. motors aren't that sensitive to supply voltage.

if you want to be safe, read the motor's datasheet if you can find one.

also, dropping some diodes /leds, appropriately sized, could help as well.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in Majenko's comment, a switch-mode buck regulator would work ok.  So would the diodes mentioned in previous answers; each ordinary silicon rectifier will drop around 0.6 - 0.8 volts, with the voltage drop increasing as current goes up.

The diodes solution wastes the dropped volts as heat.  The buck regulator would produce some heat, but typically will be more than 90% efficient.

As suggested by another comment, many motors accept wide ranges of voltage and typically are robust enough to survive wide ranges of load.  If your motor won't have too heavy a load, it may be ok with the higher voltage.  But if the load is heavy, having higher voltage and current capacity may allow the motor to burn out.

A better approach than most of the above would be to use an electronic speed control, an ESC.  These ordinarily use PWM signals to keep motor speed constant in the face of varying loads, by changing the duty cycle of pulsed DC delivered to the motor.  At slow speeds, motor power and performance can be controlled much more smoothly using PWM than by controlling voltage.